# Visual Force Page render a column only if its not NULL (Render PDF)

Tags: apex

So when I am doing RenderAs PDF , I cant use javascript . there is this column in my table that is for discount, and I want to only appear if there are discounts and in the header of the column Say "Discount". What I tried to do is this

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!Quote.Discount != null }" value="Discount"><th align="right"  style="width:70px;" ></th>
            </apex:outputText>
```

but it doesnt work. the column always shows up on some quotes and on others its all over place . I do have multiple tables, which I need to do this for
here is the code for that section

```
 <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="itemsTable" align="right">
        <tr class="itemsHeader">
            <th><strong>Test</strong></th>
            <th align="right" style="width:45px;">Qty</th>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px; Border-right: 2px solid #555555;">List Price</th>
            <th align="right"  style="width:70px;" ></th>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px; ">One-Time</th>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px;">Recurring</th>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i think you want to display the Discount column only if it exists? I'm guessing a bit because I'm not 100% sure of what you want from your description and snippet, but you could use the `<apex:outputPanel>` to hide/show the column depending on whether a value exists.

```
 <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="itemsTable" align="right">
        <tr class="itemsHeader">
            <th><strong>Test</strong></th>
            <th align="right" style="width:45px;">Qty</th>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px; Border-right: 2px solid #555555;">List Price</th>
            <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Quote.Discount)), Quote.Discount >0)}">
                <th align="right" style="width:70px;" >Discount</th>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px; ">One-Time</th>
            <th align="right" style="width:70px;">Recurring</th>
        </tr>
```

NB. Parts of my `rendered` formula may be superfluous but should do the trick. Remember to include `layout="none"` attribute/value on the `<apex:outputPanel>` because otherwise a `<span/>` would be rendered which will throw formatting off.

Comment: Thank you so much , Exactly what I was looking for. I was just using the wrong tags apex:outputText .. and everything was out of format

Comment: Can you by any chance tell me what this means or how you read it {!AND(NOT(ISBLANK(

Comment: `AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Quote.Discount)), Quote.Discount >0)` is basically the same as `Quote.Discount != null && Quote.Discount > 0` I just wasn't sure if `!= null` would work without trying

Answer (score 0):

```
rendered="{!Quote.Discount != null }"
```

You can add one more condition

```
rendered="{!Quote.Discount != null && Quote.Discount >0 }"
```

So it will only display if Discount is > 0

Comment: is what I am doing correct?

Comment: @Metawaa not completely because in controller you might have initialised the `Discount `